# Redshift truncate table with 240 rows takes 2 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_dim
(
    id BIGINT IDENTITY(0,1)
    ,source_id INTEGER
    ,name VARCHAR(200)
    ,iso2_code VARCHAR(2)
    ,iso3_code VARCHAR(3)
    ,"region" VARCHAR(200)
    ,subregion VARCHAR(200)
    ,tax_area VARCHAR(10)
    ,spanish_name VARCHAR(200)
    ,market VARCHAR(20)
    ,vat DOUBLE PRECISION  DEFAULT 0
    ,valid_from DATE  DEFAULT '1900-01-01'::date
    ,valid_to DATE
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DISTSTYLE ALL COMPOUND SORTKEY (iso2_code,valid_from,valid_to);
```

We run a script with airflow to insert rows to this table.
To do that we use the Write/Audit/Publish pattern. We insert all data into a stagins table, then we run some checks and finally we `truncate` end table and `insert` from `staging` to that.

`Truncate` operations takes 2h, but not every day. When I run it during the day I don't have any problem despite taking some minutes. The main issue appears at midnight when no one is on call and we can not check what's happening.

Could be related to the distribution style? It's a dim table used in big part of the queries.

In theory, all queries that use this table are waiting until this tasks is done as we use Airflow as an orchestrator. And as is midnight no one should be running a query against that so I am not able to imagine what's creating the block.

Comment: maybe check `stl_wlm_query` to see the actual execution time. It might give you some pointers.

Comment: @damjad I found the statement `SVL_STATEMENTTEXT` but when taking the `xid`to `stl_wlm_query` table, I am not able to find it. 

I run the script again and the query took 4 minutes. It's a lot less, but still seems a lot for a table with 250 rows.

Comment: Sounds like another query was locking some rows.

Comment: finally found it. An unknown script war running `ANALYZE;`